# What is an analytic coefficient? (Kashiwara)

Tags: partial-differential-equations, analyticity, analytic-functions, d-modules, microlocal-analysis

In [Kashiwara's thesis](http://www.numdam.org/article/MSMF_1995_2_63__R1_0.pdf) he uses $\mathcal{D}$-modules to investigate (systems of) linear PDEs with *analytic coefficients*. There are also mentions of

- analytic manifolds
- analytic linear PDEs
- analytic $\mathcal{D}$-modules
- analytic sheaves
- analytic spaces

and others...

I understand what an analytic function is.

**My question is what is an analytic coefficient?**

Is it a constant? Is it a an analytic polynomial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like an analytic coefficient means that that the coefficient can be any analytic function only depending on the independent variable.